# How do I run(and access) multiple instances of RStudio Server using Docker?

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, containers, rstudio

I have an image that I've built that is built from the `rocker` team's tidyverse `docker` image, which has multiple tools installed within the container.

This container was built for use by multiple people.

Two people are attempting to launch this image one after the other. These are the docker run commands they use:

Person 1 (who launches their container first):

```bash
docker run -d --rm -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=password -v $(pwd):/home/rstudio/mount_dir -e USERID=$(id -u) -e GROUPID=$(id -g) image:latest
```

Person 2 (who launches their container after Person 1):

```bash
docker run -d --rm -p 8788:8787 -e PASSWORD=password -v $(pwd):/home/rstudio/mount_dir -e USERID=$(id -u) -e GROUPID=$(id -g) image:latest
```

Person 1 can go to domain_name:8787 and access the RStudio interface and run it as expected.

Person 2, however, cannot find anything when they go to domain_name:8788.

The container was built by using the `rocker/tidyverse:latest` image. My Dockerfile started with:

```bash
FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest
```

**Checking if the ports mapped as expected**

I checked the output of the `docker ps -a` command to see if the containers were actually mapping the ports right.

```bash
IMAGE                    COMMAND   CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                                           NAMES
image:v1.0   "/init"   32 seconds ago   Up 30 seconds   1794/tcp, 8080/tcp, 8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8788->8787/tcp, :::8788->8787/tcp   jolly_ellis
image:v1.0             "/init"   2 hours ago     Up 2 hours     1794/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8787->8787/tcp, :::8787->8787/tcp   intelligent_sutherland                                intelligent_sutherland
```

The ports all seem to be open, the way I defined them in the Dockerfile.

**Trying different ports to map to**

I exposed multiple different ports within the Dockerfile, as you can see from the output of the `docker ps -a` command, and I tried mapping a different port from outside a container to a seperate port (that is already exposed) inside the container. That didn't work either.

Person 1:

```bash
-p 8787:8787
```

Person 2:

```bash
# Trying a different host port
-p 8788:8787
```

```bash
# Trying a different host port to a different (exposed) container port
-p 8788:8888
```

None of these seem to work for person 2.

**Using a private browser window**

I have searched for potential solutions to this issue, and saw that other people had success with using a private window, since the cookies for a private window are separate from regular tabs. That didn't work either.

How do I go about fixing this? I want for the users to be able to launch multiple containers from  the RStudio same server image and be able to use them at the same time.

Comment: If it is about launching the same container for multiple people accessing web applications I propose to look into ShinyProxy / ConatinerProxy, e.g. https://www.shinyproxy.io/

Comment: I specifically mentioned needing to launch multiple containers in my question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, my answer was misleading, I meant to say that ContainerProxy can start multiple containers from the same image, all would be accessible on the same port for different users as the proxy handles the port mapping itself, see https://containerproxy.io/ Sorry for the confusion.